# Enabling CSP policy causing javascript on frontend to NOT send cookies and referrer header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-security-policy

If i remove CSP policy from backend, nodejs. Then everything works. But if I enable it, javascript breaks.

To look further I checked request headers of ajax requests being made my by js files. There are two big differences: a) no cookies are being sent, b) no referrer header is being sent.

To me it's a mystery.

csp string:

```
Content-Security-Policy: 
default-src 'self'; 
script-src 'self' ...; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ...; 
font-src 'self' ..; 
img-src 'self' data: ..; 
sandbox allow-forms allow-scripts; 
report-uri /report-violation; 
object-src 'none'; 
worker-src 'self' ..; 
frame-src 'self' h..;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `sandbox` directive, or add `allow-same-origin` to it. By default, the `sandbox` clause treats all embedded content (including scripts!) as coming from a unique origin, which prevents it from using your site's cookies.

Comment: amazing you knew that, I spent like 3 hours through process of elimination and just found it.